# Python 2.7 symlink() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, windows, nlp, spacy

I got an error while trying to run python spaCy via jupyter notebook

```
ValueError: Found English model at c:\python27\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en-1.1.0. This model is not compatible with the current version. See https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models to download the new model.
```

Then I tried updating the spacy en model using

```
python -m spacy download en
```

And I get the following error

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 30, in download
cli_download(model, direct)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 25, in download
link_package(model_name, model, force=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\link.py", line 27, in link_package
symlink(model_path, link_name, force)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\link.py", line 46, in symlink
link_path.symlink_to(model_path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 1163, in symlink_to
self._accessor.symlink(target, self, target_is_directory)
TypeError: symlink() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I am using Python 2.7 32-bit on Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Someone provided an answer to this question, although it was not accepted since the user chose to move to Ubuntu. Maybe it would work in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914239/spacy-english-model-install-is-failing

Comment: Well.. I do not know about spaCy or Jupiter, but you could try to figure out what is happening.. maybe add a 4th argument to `self._accessor.symlink` on line 1163 of pathlib.py and then make the function print out all its arguments.. this well help you see which 4 arguments are being passed, maybe 1 is obviously wrong and you can trace it back via your errortrace.. Would be a last resort solution though..